# Adding calculated field to Excel chart

Tags: excel, charts, excel-formula

Can you add a calculated field to a chart?  I have a very simple table that shows each day in June and a count for each day.  I created the table and everything looks good so far.

What I would like to do is add 2 fields: (1) the completed count and (2) the remaining items.  So the total count in 90 and I would like the remaining items to show 90 - (sum of counts).

If the current total is 6, one field would display 6 and the other would display 84.  Then every day once the count is added for that particular day, the chart would be automatically updated.

I've been able to add text boxes but haven't been able to get them to display the appropriate values.

Is this even possible and if so, how do I get the appropriate values to display.

Thanks for your help.  I'm using Excel 2016 (if that makes a difference).........Thanks again

Comment: Calculated field and items are a part of pivot tables/charts

Comment: Sounds it should be possible. Do you have any sample data so we can get a feeling of what data you have and what your desired output should look like?

Comment: @wizhi......the table is 2 columns.  Column 1 has the date for each day in June. The second column will have a number between 0 and 5.  The total of of column 2 is 90.  The chart looks fine.  I wan to add 2 fields.  The 1st will show the total completed to date while the second will show how many remain.  So each day after entering the number in column 2, I can see the number completed and remaining.  A snapshot for the month.  Thanks....These would be outside the chart area.  Maybe next to the legend ot chart title....